# Unable to generate database table using Entity Framework Code First approach

Tags: ef-code-first

Written the following simple code to learn about Entity Framework Code First approach. But, I am unable to make it work.

Not getting any error as well. When verified the generated .mdf file, no record found.

Unable to identify the problem even while debugging the code. Can anyone please suggest me where I am doing wrong!

Below is my code.

Below is the Person class

```
namespace EFCF
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the context class

```
namespace EFCF
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the test program written in Console Application.

```
namespace TestEFCF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Insert person record
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
                Person person = new Person
                {
                    PersonId = 1001,
                    FirstName = "Ashok",
                    LastName = "Kumar"
                };
                context.Persons.Add(person);
            }

            //Get person record
            using (Context context = new Context())
            {
                var people = context.Persons;
                foreach (var person in people)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(person.PersonId + "\t" + person.FirstName + "\t" + person.LastName);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run `Add-Migration <YourMigrationName>` and then `Update-Database` commands in Package Manager Console?

Comment: No, but why do we need to run Add-Migration command? I have not done any changes to Person class. If I need to run Add-Migration, please suggest me how I have to do?

Comment: Is `Person` table already exists? Or you have modified/removed/added any column to `Person` table?

Comment: @vivek nuna: No, Person class is just written in class library project

Comment: So ..are you trying to create a new table `Person`? Right?

Comment: @viveknuna: yes

Comment: So you have to generate migration first using `Add-Migration <YourMigrationName>` command(its eqivelant to generating the migration script in DB first approach) then you have to run `Update-Database` command (it is eqivalent to running the migration script in DB first appraoch)from package manager console in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you using entity framework or entity framework core?

Comment: @viveknuna: I'm using Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake in my previous code.

No need to enable migrations for this particular situation. Just add `context.SaveChanges()` command at the right place as shown below.

Below is the complete code.

```
        //Insert person record
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            Person person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Ashok",
                LastName = "Kumar"
            };
            context.Persons.Add(person);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first run `Add-Migration <YourMigrationName>` command (its equivalent to generating the migration script in DB first approach)from Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. Then run `Update-Database` command (it is equivalent to running the migration script in DB first approach)to apply the migration.

You can refer [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx) page for details information.

Note: Remove the unnecessary code from C# code to generate the database.